# Como mudar a cor do cursor brilhante do EditText?

Tags: android, android-xml

[image: EditText com o cursor rosa]

Gostava de saber qual o nome do atributo que muda aquela barra de cor,Obrigado.

Answer (score 4):

O *EditText* tem um atributo que define o *drawable* a utilizar para o cursor.

Crie o *drawable*:

**my_cursor.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <size android:width="1dp" />
    <solid android:color="#FF0000"  />
</shape>
```

`size android:width` define a espessura.
`solid android:color` define a cor.

Atribua esse *drawable* ao atributo `android:textCursorDrawable`:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/my_cursor"/>
```